# Django Querying Relation

Tags: python, django

the code did not return all of the item's name based on employee..? how to solve this probem? did the models wrong? or the query?

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField()


class Item(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()


class Inventory(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventaris-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**VIEWS.PY**
*how can i get all of the employee's item ?*

```
query_set = Inventory.objects.all()

    for query in query_set:
        output.append([
            query.employee.name,
            query.item.name
        ])
```

i need something like `query.employee.items_set.all()` .. ?

Comment: It is not entirely clear *what* you here aim to do. What is the input? What should be the output?

Comment: i want to have the output of all of the emloyees items, but code above likely just print out each individual employees and individual items in the inventory models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get all of the items from an employee? The following should achieve that:

```
employee = Employee.objects.all()[0]  # Just get a random employee, you can do this with more employees too if you want
employees_items = [inventory.item for inventory in employee.inventory_set.all()]
```

Your code does not logically make a lot of sense though, to be honest. Most likely, there should be a field on a `Item` class which is a FK to `Inventory`. Your item class should probably be:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

(Of course this will not work since Inventory is defined after this class, but you can just put Inventory above it or use one of the other many methods to solve this problem)

Good luck!

Comment: but in the Inventory model has item, which is called first before even declared ._.

what should be the recommended order

Comment: Remove `item` from `Inventory` model, and put the `Inventory` model above `Item.` It makes more sense that way :)

Comment: employees_items = [inventory.item for inventory in employee.inventory_set.all()] ... this inventory doesn't recognize .item ,,, inventory object has no atribute item

Comment: well if you made the changes that I made, then of course my answer will no longer work :) my original answer was based on the original model configuration. If the Inventory model has no field called item, then you cannot call item on an Inventory instance.